# Accept.js issue with Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: authorize.net

We are facing an issue with Accept.js library with Internet Explorer v11. The browser console showing following error while the same code is working good in other browser.

- Access is denied.
- Unable to get property 'dispatchData' of undefined or null reference.

Please let us know if there is any workaround we can do to fix the issue for IE. The card is not getting validated with accept js also the nonce is not getting generated because of this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you loading the scripts from a different domain?

Comment: No, we are using accept.js global url only, and as I mentioned its working with other browser, the issue is only with internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://nexwebsites.com/authorizenet/acceptjs.aspx with your copy of IE 11, as I am now and not getting any errors. This posts to the sandbox, so you can use card #: 4012888818888, any future expiration date, and any CVV.

If you receive no errors, then the issue is with your implementation. In this case, you should post your code, to be better helped.